# Do we get Lyman like emission after proton capture?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

If an atoms nucleus absorbs a proton following proton bombardment its potential well would get correspondingly deeper.

Would electrons in the atoms orbital then be affected?

(A crude analogy might be the effect in the moon if the earth gained significant mass)

Would those orbital electrons transition to the deeper orbital energy state emitting Lyman like emissions?

If so do we see something similar after beta decay of a nucleus?

If a proton transitions within the S1 orbital of an atom for sufficient time would we see similar emissions during the time of transit?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking in your last paragraph so my answer does not address that question.

Answer (score 0):

The capture of a proton by a nucleus does not yield a deeper potential (it's already infinitely deep, $Z/r$), but it does increase the binding of electron orbitals.  The same occurs in beta decay. The emitted radiation is not Lyman like (it is more complicated).  It involves the rearrangement of all of the effected orbitals. I'll leave it to an experimentalist  to describe what is actually observed.